# Custom Model relation with Django User Model Pls help i am new to Django rest Api

Tags: python, django, api

I am new to Django Rest API for user model i am using Django default user model. my end end goal is when user login he will able to see data only related to him

**I want my value like this**

```
{ "user": 1
    {
      "id": 1,
      "rent_date": "23-08-2022",
      "rentmonth": "June",
      "rent_amount": 5000.0,
      "bijli_bill": 250.0,
      "other_amount": 150.0,
      "other_commnet": "test",
      "total_amount": 5400.0,
      "total_rent_amount": 17000.0,
    }
}
```

**But Getting like this, user showing under rent model**

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "rent_date": "23-08-2022",
      "rentmonth": "June",
      "rent_amount": 5000.0,
      "bijli_bill": 250.0,
      "other_amount": 150.0,
      "other_commnet": "test",
      "total_amount": 5400.0,
      "total_rent_amount": 17000.0,
      "user": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "rent_date": "23-08-2022",
      "rentmonth": "July",
      "rent_amount": 6000.0,
      "bijli_bill": 250.0,
      "other_amount": 150.0,
      "other_commnet": "test",
      "total_amount": 6400.0,
      "total_rent_amount": 17000.0,
      "user": 2
    },
```

**This is my Model.py**
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

```
class rent(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rent_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    rentmonth = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    rent_amount = models.FloatField()
    bijli_bill = models.FloatField()
    other_amount = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    other_commnet = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200)

    @property
    def total_amount(self):
        return self.rent_amount + self.bijli_bill + self.other_amount
```

**this my serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import rent
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import Sum

class rentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rent_date = serializers.DateField(format="%d-%m-%Y", read_only=True)
    rentmonth = serializers.CharField()
    rent_amount = serializers.FloatField()
    bijli_bill = serializers.FloatField()
    other_amount = serializers.FloatField()
    other_commnet = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    total_amount = serializers.FloatField()
    total_rent_amount = serializers.SerializerMethodField()


    class Meta:
        model = rent
        fields = ('__all__')

    def get_total_rent_amount(self, obj):
        totalprice = rent.objects.all().aggregate(total_price=Sum('rent_amount'))
        return totalprice["total_price"]

    

# User Serializer
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email')

# Register Serializer
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(validated_data['username'], validated_data['email'], validated_data['password'])

        return user
```

**Here is my view.py**

```
 class rentViews(APIView):
        def post(self, request):
            serializer = rentSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                return Response({"status": "error", "data": serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    
        def get(self, request, id=None):
            if id:
                item = rent.objects.get(id=id)
                serializer = rentSerializer(item)
                return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    
            items = rent.objects.all()
            serializer = rentSerializer(items, many=True)
            return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    
        def patch(self, request, id=None):
            item = rent.objects.get(id=id)
            serializer = rentSerializer(item, data=request.data, partial=True)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data})
            else:
                return Response({"status": "error", "data": serializer.errors})
    
        def delete(self, request, id=None):
            item = get_object_or_404(rent, id=id)
            item.delete()
            return Response({"status": "success", "data": "Item Deleted"})
    ###############################UserAPI#######################################
    
    # Register API
    class RegisterAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
        serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
    
        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            user = serializer.save()
            return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
            })
    
    # Login API
    class LoginAPI(KnoxLoginView):
        permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    
        def post(self, request, format=None):
            serializer = AuthTokenSerializer(data=request.data)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            user = serializer.validated_data['user']
            login(request, user)
            return super(LoginAPI, self).post(request, format=None)
```

Comment: Please add the view/viewset that returns that response

Comment: @Iain Shelvington I have view.py file

Comment: Okay, can you add the view code to your question?

Comment: @Iain Shelvington Pls check

Comment: write a `to_representation` method in return the json(dict) however you want.